# Parsing XML using PHP - Which includes ampersands and other characters

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I'm trying to parse an XML file and one of the fields looks like the following:

```
<link>http://foo.com/this-platform/scripts/click.php?var_a=a&var_b=b&varc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.foo.com%2Fthis-section-here%2Fperf%2F229408%3Fvalue%3D0222%26some_variable%3Dmeee</link>
```

This seems to break the parser.  i think it might be something to do with the & in the link?

My code is quite simple:

```
<?

$xml = simplexml_load_file("files/this.xml");

echo $xml->getName() . "<br />";

foreach($xml->children() as $child) {
  echo $child->getName() . ": " . $child . "<br />";
}
?>
```

any ideas how i can resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment by [mjv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166686/mjv) resolved it:

> Alternatively to using &, you may
>   consider putting the urls and other
>   XML-unfriendly content in
>   , i.e. a
>   Character Data block

Answer (score 4):

The XML snippet you posted is not valid. Ampersands have to be escaped, this is why the parser complaints.

Comment: I can't change the feed unfortunately, so there is no other way other than regex to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Your XML feed is not valid XML : the `&` should be escaped as `&amp;`

This means you cannot use an XML parser on it :-(

A possible "solution" *(feels wrong, but should work)* would be to replace '`&`' that are not part of an entity by '`&amp;`', to get a valid XML string before loading it with an XML parser.

In your case, considering this :

```
$str = <<<STR
<xml>
  <link>http://foo.com/this-platform/scripts/click.php?var_a=a&var_b=b&varc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.foo.com%2Fthis-section-here%2Fperf%2F229408%3Fvalue%3D0222%26some_variable%3Dmeee</link>
</xml>
STR;
```

You might use a simple call to [`str_replace`](http://www.php.net/str_replace), like this :

```
$str = str_replace('&', '&amp;', $str);
```

And, then, parse the string *(now XML-valid)* that's in `$str` :

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);
var_dump($xml);
```

In this case, it should work...

But note that you must take care about entities : if you already have an entity like '`&gt;`', you must not replace it to '`&amp;gt;`' !

Which means that such a simple call to `str_replace` is not the right solution : it will probably break stuff on many XML feeds !

Up to you to find the right way to do that replacement -- maybe with some kind of regex...

Answer (score 2):

It breaks the parser because your XML is invalid - `&` should be encoded as `&amp;`.

Comment: Alternatively to using &amp;, you may consider putting the urls and other XML-unfriendly content in <![CDATA[your_stuff_here]]>, i.e. a Character Data block

Comment: I can't change the feed unfortunately, so there is no other way other than regex to do this? Will this: <link><![CDATA[link]]></link> fix it? (if i can change the file?)

Comment: Mjv - if you want to place your comment in the form of an answer i will accept as it's made life easier now and my xml "valid"...

Answer (score 1):

If your XML already has some escaping, this way it will be preserved and unescaped ampersands will be fixed:

```
$brokenXmlText = file_get_contents("files/this.xml");
$fixed = preg_replace('/&(?!lt;|gt;|quot;|apos;|amp;|#)/', '&amp;', $brokenXmlText);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($fixed);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you 
 http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-errors.php#96218